# add key price = page count in book for all books in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

add key price = page count in book for all books in mongodb

How to do the query please comment below and help me

Comment: Please provide example of your data.

Comment: i am using book data : {
        "title" : "Unlocking Android",
        "pageCount" : 416,
        "publishedDate" : ISODate("2009-04-01T07:00:00Z"),
        "authors" : [
                "W. Frank Ableson",   ],
        "categories" : [
                "Open Source"],
        }

Comment: i tried this but it will not add new column it and i want to add the price and give pageCount value in single query >db.book.aggregate ({$project : {pageCount :1 , price : '$pageCount' }})